# Why I obtain an "Illegal line end in string literal" when I try to put the "\" character into a Java String?

Tags: java, string

Working on a Java application I have the following problem trying to create a String that represent a path into the file system.

So I am trying to do something like this:

```
String result = appFileSystemLocation + "\" + pdfName;
```

But the problem is that IntelliJ give me the following error message on the

> \ character: Illegal line end in string litteral

Why? How can I solve this issue and how can I correctly concatenate the `\` character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\` is the escaping character, it's used to escape other characters in [Java String literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5). It's used for example in `\"`, which is how you put a `"` in a string, that's why your string appears as unfinished (see also the colorization of the end of line in your question).

You must escape it :

```
String result = appFileSystemLocation + "\\" + pdfName;
```